# drain() vs flush() in ObjectOutputStream Class in Java

Tags: java

When I saw descriptions about these two methods as below, I felt a bit confused about them.

> `protected void drain()`: Similar to flush but does not propagate the flush to the underlying stream.
>
> `void flush()`: Writes any buffered output bytes and flush through to the underlying stream.

For example:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");   

ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
```

Question 1:
If I call `oout.flush()`, it will force the output data in the ObjectOutputStream to be written to the underlying FileOutputStream, but it doesn't guarantee that these data will be subsequently written from FileOutputStream to the file "test.txt" in the disk since I don't call `out.flush()`, is this correct?

Question 2:
What if I call `oout.drain()`?

- What executions will be done?

Comment: Well, for starters `drain()` is protected, not public, so it's only designed to be called by sub-classes.  In other words it's part of the class's internal implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to know how it'll be executed. It's about implementation details.

Comment: In the future if you have questions like this, it doesn't hurt to Google "grecode java <class>".  Grepcode is a website which lists source code form many open source projects, including the JDK.  If I have questions about how something is implemented I normally check there first.

Comment: So after doing just that, what `drain()` actually does appears to be a `write()` to the underlying IO stream.  You can't depend on them keeping internal implementation the same in the future, but reading the source gives imo a better idea what the original implementer was thinking when they wrote the method and documentation.  It's just handy to know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Question 1:
>
> If I call `oout.flush(),` it will force the output data in the `ObjectOutputStream` to be written to the underlying `FileOutputStream,` but it doesn't guarantee that these data will be subsequently written from `FileOutputStream` to the file "test.txt" in the disk since I don't call `out.flush()`, am I right?

No, you are wrong. It *does* flush the `FileOutputStream`. However, as `FileOutputStream` doesn't buffer or flush, in fact there is no difference between `drain()` and `flush()` in this circumstance. If there had been a `BufferedOutputStream` around the `FileOutputStream`, there would have been a difference.

> Question 2:
>
> What if I call `oout.drain()`? What executions will be done?

It will flush the `ObjectOutputStream` but not the underlying stream, exactly as it says in the Javadoc.

You have somehow managed to get this completely back to front. I can't understand how: the Javadoc is quite clear. Also, as `drain()` is `protected` it is none of your business anyway.

Comment: So according to your answer, if I wrap    BufferedOutputStream around 
   FileOutputStream,    drain() will only flush    ObjectOutputStream, whereas    flush() will flush both    ObjectOutputStream and undelying 
   BufferedOutputStream. Is this correct?

Comment: There is no point whatsoever in elaborating all the possible scenarios. The statement 'it will flush the `ObjectOutputStream` but not the underlying stream' is perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 1):

Flush will write the data to the test.txt. However, drain is similar to flush but does not propagate the flush to the underlying stream.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to how it is executed rather than scripts or descriptions from java documents.

Comment: @Clemont How it is executed is exactly as stated in the 'descriptions from Java documents'. That's what they are for.